# C# XML Serialization Observable Collection

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize a bunch of data that was serialized by an old version of the code. When the data was serialized the classes had a different structure from the current class structure. To keep this data working in my new code, I hade to add the old classes structure to the code just for import this serialized data. I'm calling this classes as 'class'_oldVersions. To deserialize, I'm using this code:

```
className_oldVersions temp_className = new className_oldVersions();

XmlSerializer testSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(className_oldVersions), 
   new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "className" });

temp_className = (ObservedData_OldVersions)testSerializer.Deserialize(ms_MemoryStream);
```

This code works fine, and I can deserialize the data using a diffent class name from the original. My problem is when I try to use this same procedure to deserialize an observable collection.

I created a code that reproduce my problem. In this code I serialize an observable collection of class OptimizationVariables and I would like to deserialize to an observable collection of class OptimizationVariablies_NewClass that has similar structure from the original one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class OptimizationVariables
{
  public string VariableName { get; set; }    
}

public class OptimizationVariables_NewClass
{
  public string VariableName { get; set; }
}

public class ModelsCollection
{
  private ModelsCollection()
  {
  }    

  private ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> m_optimizationVariables =
    new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>();

  public ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> OptimizationVariables
  {
    get { return m_optimizationVariables; }
    set { m_optimizationVariables = value; }
  }

  private ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass> m_optimizationVariables_NewClass =
    new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>();

  public ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass> OptimizationVariables_NewClass
  {
    get { return m_optimizationVariables_NewClass; }
    set { m_optimizationVariables_NewClass = value; }
  }


}
class Program
{   

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    //Here I serialize an ObservableCollection of 2 OptimizationVariables instances
    Serialize();

    //Here I deserialize for the same class and works fine
    Deserialize();

    //Here I try to deserialize to a new class with same structure, but different name. I a have an error.
    Deserialize2NewClass();
  }


  static void Serialize()
  {
    MemoryStream ms;

    ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> OptimizationVariables2Serialize = new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>();

    OptimizationVariables opt_var1 = new OptimizationVariables();
    opt_var1.VariableName = "Variable Name 1";
    OptimizationVariables2Serialize.Add(opt_var1);

    OptimizationVariables opt_var2 = new OptimizationVariables();
    opt_var1.VariableName = "Variable Name 2";
    OptimizationVariables2Serialize.Add(opt_var1);

    ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>));
    serializer.Serialize(ms, OptimizationVariables2Serialize);

    TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("XML_File_x64.bin");
    sw.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()));
    sw.Close();
  }

  static void Deserialize()
  {
    byte[] memoryData;
    MemoryStream ms;

    TextReader sw = new StreamReader("XML_File_x64.bin");
    memoryData = Convert.FromBase64String(sw.ReadLine());
    ms = new MemoryStream(memoryData);

    ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>();

    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>));
    OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = (ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>)deserializer.Deserialize(ms);

    Console.Write(OptimizationVariablesDeserialized.Count());
    sw.Close();
  }

  static void Deserialize2NewClass()
  {
    byte[] memoryData;
    MemoryStream ms;

    TextReader sw = new StreamReader("XML_File_x64.bin");
    memoryData = Convert.FromBase64String(sw.ReadLine());
    ms = new MemoryStream(memoryData);

    ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass> OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>();

    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>));
    OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = (ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>)deserializer.Deserialize(ms);

    Console.Write(OptimizationVariablesDeserialized.Count());
    sw.Close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the class OptimizationVariables name is saved in the xml data when serializing. but for deserialization it expects a OptimizationVariables_NewClass name which is not within the xml file.

- consider the fact that not only the variable names, but also the class names will be used when serializing a class or struct...

So, just changed your code to make it save the data in readable xml file, then replacing "OptimizationVariables" with "OptimizationVariables_NewClass" solved the error:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class OptimizationVariables
{
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
}

public class OptimizationVariables_NewClass
{
    public string VariableName { get; set; }
}

public class ModelsCollection
{
private ModelsCollection()
{
}

private ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> m_optimizationVariables =
  new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>();

public ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> OptimizationVariables
{
    get { return m_optimizationVariables; }
    set { m_optimizationVariables = value; }
}

private ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass> m_optimizationVariables_NewClass =
  new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>();

public ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass> OptimizationVariables_NewClass
{
    get { return m_optimizationVariables_NewClass; }
    set { m_optimizationVariables_NewClass = value; }
}


}
class Program
{

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Serialize();
    Deserialize();
    Deserialize2NewClass();
}

static void Serialize()
{
    ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> OptimizationVariables2Serialize = new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>();

    OptimizationVariables opt_var1 = new OptimizationVariables();
    opt_var1.VariableName = "Variable Name 1";
    OptimizationVariables2Serialize.Add(opt_var1);

    OptimizationVariables opt_var2 = new OptimizationVariables();
    opt_var1.VariableName = "Variable Name 2";
    OptimizationVariables2Serialize.Add(opt_var1);

    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("XML_File.xml");
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, OptimizationVariables2Serialize);
    writer.Close();
}

static void Deserialize()
{
    TextReader sw = new StreamReader("XML_File.xml");

    ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables> OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>();

    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>));
    OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = (ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables>)deserializer.Deserialize(sw);

    Console.Write(OptimizationVariablesDeserialized.Count());
    sw.Close();
}

static void Deserialize2NewClass()
{
    TextReader sw = new StreamReader("XML_File.xml");
    var str = sw.ReadToEnd();
    sw.Close();
    str = str.Replace("OptimizationVariables", "OptimizationVariables_NewClass");
    var stream = new StringReader(str);
    ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass> OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = new ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>();

    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>));
    OptimizationVariablesDeserialized = (ObservableCollection<OptimizationVariables_NewClass>)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);

    Console.Write(OptimizationVariablesDeserialized.Count());
}

}
```

now it works fine!